# avoid linebreak in \lstinline if possible

Tags: listings, line-breaking, inline

By using `\lstinline{mysourcecode}` I put some code within my document.

I would like to avoid that this code is broken to a new line, if possible.
so, if the codeline itself is less long than a full textline, then I would like `LaTeX` to make no linebreak if the code is somewhere in the middle of the textline, but make the linebreak before `\lstline` if not doing so would cause the code onto two lines.

How to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please rephrase your question and include proper punctuation. Having three if-clauses into one "sentence" is a little confusing. It would be even better if you actually add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows all cases.

Answer (score 8):

The following MWE provides `\lstInline[<options>]{<code snippet>}` as a complement to `\lstinline` that tests whether the in-line code will fit within the remainder of the line, otherwise it issues a line break.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linegoal,listings}
\newsavebox{\mylisting}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lstInline}[2][,]{%
  \begingroup%
  \lstset{#1}% Set any keys locally
  \begin{lrbox}{\mylisting}\lstinline!#2!\end{lrbox}% Store listing in \mylisting
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\linegoal}% Space left on line.
  \ifdim\wd\mylisting>\@tempdima\hfill\\\fi% Insert line break
  \lstinline!#2!% Reset listing
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
Here is some text and \lstinline!some code segment! as well. \par
Here is some text and \lstInline{some code segment} as well. \par
Here is some text, then a little more text, 
  and finally there is also \lstinline!some code segment! as well. \par
Here is some text, then a little more text, 
  and finally there is also \lstInline{some code segment} as well. \par
\end{document}
```

The driver behind the line break conditioning comes from the [`linegoal` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) the relies on [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module. `\lstinline` is first set within a box `\mylisting` inside `\lstInline`, to establish its width. If it exceeds `\linegoal` (the remaining space available on the line), a line break in the form `\hfill\\` is issued, after which `\lstinline` is called again.

Resetting `\lstinline` (rather than just using the boxed value `\usebox{\mylisting}`) allows for the code segment to wrap around multiple lines and also properly stretch/shrink, if needed, within the regular text.

Any changes in the start position of the code segment will require a recompile to properly work - a requirement when working with the `\label`-`\ref` system provided by `linegoal`.

Note that `\lstInline` uses `\lstinline!...!` with `!` as the character delimiter. As such there will be problems when actually using `!` in the inline listing. If this is a problem, just use an alternate character inside the definition.

Comment: I see one issue when I try to write `\lstInline|#    elif defined(__GNUC__) && !wxCHECK_GCC_VERSION(4, 5)|`, this is the error `! You can't use macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.`, any ideas?

Comment: @ollydbg23: Maybe consider manual intervention here. That is, insert a line break and then set it in a normal `\lstinline`.